# JSON won't load 'state_id' or any other things that I add to the mock

Tags: javascript, python, xml, postgresql, odoo

I'm trying to fully create a sale order, right now it works and creates the sale order for odoo but I need the json to send me the 'state_id' so I can know where the sale.order come from, right now this is the log I get from the self.data and data after the json.loads(self.data) goes on

```
Received JSON data: {"Sale": [{"Customer_ref": "CUST-001", "Clients": [{"Vat": "123456789", "Name": "Oscarino", "Last_name": "Perezihno", "Email": "oPerez@example.com", "Street": "Street 1", "Street2": "Street 2", "Country_id": "ES", "zip": "45020"}], "Product": [{"Barcode": "0001", "Quantity": 1, "Price": 10.0}]}, {"Customer_ref": "CUST-002", "Clients": [{"Vat": "987654321", "Name": "nachito", "Last_name": "nachon", "Email": "test@example.com", "Street": "Street 3", "Street2": "Street 4", "Country_id": "ES", "zip": "28020"}], "Product": [{"Barcode": "0002", "Quantity": 2, "Price": 20.0}]}]}
```

I'm running this code with a cron on odoo 16 enterprise on premise, both files are correctly imported and stated on manifest for them to work, as I stated as details, it fully creates a sale.order but it doesn't bring the state_id from the JSON mock

```
import logging
import json 
import requests
from odoo import api, models, fields, Command

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class JsonHandler(models.Model):
    _name = 'iop.handler'
    
    data = fields.Char('IOP JSON Data')

    @api.model
    def create_sale_order(self):
        data = json.loads(self.data) 
        _logger.info("Received JSON data:\n%s", json.dumps(data, indent=4))  # Log the original JSON data with indent
        Sale = data['Sale']
        for sale in Sale:
            if 'Clients' in sale and len(sale['Clients']) > 0:
                client = sale['Clients'][0]
                
                vat = client.get('Vat')
                _logger.info("Processing VAT: %s", vat)  
                partner = self.env['res.partner'].search([('vat', '=', vat)], limit=1)
                if not partner:
                    name = client.get('Name', '')
                    last_name = client.get('Last_name', '')
                    email = client.get('Email')
                    street = client.get('Street')
                    street2 = client.get('Street2')
                    zip_code = client.get('zip')
                    country_id = self.env['res.country'].search([('code', '=', client.get('Country_id', '').split('/')[0])], limit=1).id
                    state_id = self.env['res.country.state'].search([('name', '=', client.get('state_id', '').split('/')[0])], limit=1).id 
                    partner = self.env['res.partner'].create({
                        'name': name + ' ' + last_name,
                        'vat': vat,
                        'email': email,
                        'street': street,
                        'street2': street2,
                        'country_id': country_id,
                        'state_id': state_id,
                        'zip': zip_code,
                    })      
                _logger.info("Created partner for VAT: %s", vat)

                order_values = {
                    'name': sale['Customer_ref'],
                    'partner_id': partner.id,
                    'order_line': [],
                }
                _logger.info("Creating sale order with values: %s", order_values)

                if 'Product' in sale:
                    for product in sale['Product']:
                        product_id = self.env['product.product'].search([('barcode', '=', str(product['Barcode']))], limit=1)
                        if product_id and 'Quantity' in product:
                            quantity = product.get('Quantity')
                            price = product.get('Price')
                            order_values['order_line'].append(Command.create({
                                'product_id': product_id.id,
                                'product_uom_qty': quantity,
                                'price_unit': price,
                            }))

                self.env['sale.order'].create(order_values)


    @api.model
    def cron_create_sale_order(self):
        handlers = self.search([])
        if not handlers:
            handlers = self.create_handler()
        for handler in handlers:
            handler.create_sale_order()
            
    @api.model
    def create_handler(self):
        iop_handler = self.env['iop.handler'].create({
        'data': json.dumps({
            "Sale": [
                {
                    "Customer_ref": "CUST-001",
                    "Clients": [
                        {
                            "Vat": "123456789",
                            "Name": "Oscarino",
                            "Last_name": "Perezihno",
                            "Email": "oPerez@example.com",
                            "Street": "Street 1",
                            "Street2": "Street 2",
                            "Country_id": "ES",
                            "state_id": "Murcia",
                            "zip": "45020"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Product": [
                        {
                            "Barcode": "0001",
                            "Quantity": 1,
                            "Price": 10.0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Customer_ref": "CUST-002",
                    "Clients": [
                        {
                            "Vat": "987654321",
                            "Name": "nachito",
                            "Last_name": "nachon",
                            "Email": "test@example.com",
                            "Street": "Street 3",
                            "Street2": "Street 4",
                            "Country_id": "ES",
                            "state_id": "Madrid",
                            "zip": "28020"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Product": [
                        {
                            "Barcode": "0002",
                            "Quantity": 2,
                            "Price": 20.0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, indent=4),
    })

        return iop_handler
```

this is the cron

```
<odoo>
<record id="ir_cron_create_sale_order" model="ir.cron">
    <field name="name">Create Sale Order from JSON Data</field>
    <field name="interval_number">1</field>
    <field name="interval_type">hours</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field name="doall">0</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="iopSaleOrder.model_iop_handler"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">model.cron_create_sale_order()</field>
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
</record>

</odoo>
```

I tested it on jupyter like this, previously importing json and logging:

```
data = {
    'Sale': [
        {
            'Customer_ref': 'CUST-001',
            'Clients': [
                {
                    'Vat': '123456789',
                    'Name': 'Oscarino',
                    'Last_name': 'Perezihno',
                    'Email': 'oPerez@example.com',
                    'Street': 'Street 1',
                    'Street2': 'Street 2',
                    'Country_id': 'ES',
                    'state_id': 'Murcia',
                    'zip': '45020',
                },
            ],
            'Product': [
                {
                    'Barcode': '0001',
                    'Quantity': 1,
                    'Price': 10.0,
                },  
            ],
        },
        {
            'Customer_ref': 'CUST-002',
            'Clients': [
                {
                    'Vat': '987654321',
                    'Name': 'nachito',
                    'Last_name': 'nachon',
                    'Email': 'test@example.com',
                    'Street': 'Street 3',
                    'Street2': 'Street 4',
                    'Country_id': 'ES',
                    'state_id': 'Madrid',
                    'zip': '28020',
                },
            ],
            'Product': [
                {
                    'Barcode': '0002',
                    'Quantity': 2,
                    'Price': 20.0,
                },  
            ],
        }
    ]
}

# Here you convert your data into a JSON string
json_data = json.dumps(data)

# Then you can print the JSON string to verify it
print(json_data)

# And you can load it back into a Python dictionary to make sure it converts back correctly
loaded_data = json.loads(json_data)
print(loaded_data)
```

this outcome with jup was this

```
{"Sale": [{"Customer_ref": "CUST-001", "Clients": [{"Vat": "123456789", "Name": "Oscarino", "Last_name": "Perezihno", "Email": "oPerez@example.com", "Street": "Street 1", "Street2": "Street 2", "Country_id": "ES", "state_id": "Murcia", "zip": "45020"}], "Product": [{"Barcode": "0001", "Quantity": 1, "Price": 10.0}]}, {"Customer_ref": "CUST-002", "Clients": [{"Vat": "987654321", "Name": "nachito", "Last_name": "nachon", "Email": "test@example.com", "Street": "Street 3", "Street2": "Street 4", "Country_id": "ES", "state_id": "Madrid", "zip": "28020"}], "Product": [{"Barcode": "0002", "Quantity": 2, "Price": 20.0}]}]}
{'Sale': [{'Customer_ref': 'CUST-001', 'Clients': [{'Vat': '123456789', 'Name': 'Oscarino', 'Last_name': 'Perezihno', 'Email': 'oPerez@example.com', 'Street': 'Street 1', 'Street2': 'Street 2', 'Country_id': 'ES', 'state_id': 'Murcia', 'zip': '45020'}], 'Product': [{'Barcode': '0001', 'Quantity': 1, 'Price': 10.0}]}, {'Customer_ref': 'CUST-002', 'Clients': [{'Vat': '987654321', 'Name': 'nachito', 'Last_name': 'nachon', 'Email': 'test@example.com', 'Street': 'Street 3', 'Street2': 'Street 4', 'Country_id': 'ES', 'state_id': 'Madrid', 'zip': '28020'}], 'Product': [{'Barcode': '0002', 'Quantity': 2, 'Price': 20.0}]}]}
```

This makes me think that maybe something is wrong with my mock json.dump for create_handler()

https://github.com/JessieDani/PsSaleOrder

Edit: added indent=4 for better formating for JSON

Comment: Your json data is extremely hard to read, I had to load it and redump it to understand it correctly. Use `indent=4` in your `json.dumps` calls, it will make your JSON output human readable.

Comment: I'm sorry @ΞένηΓήινος I'm super new to odoo and python, kinda learning, let me try it

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Added the indent=4 for format, you were right it's wayyy better to read it that way, updated the Question with indent and added github for easy testing

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but are you sure you have those states in your database?

Comment: @CZoellner I believe so, I took their name by the fed. state tab in contacts for odoo, but they problem seems like the json.loads() or the dump is not working correctly, that's my guess since the whenever I ran the log after loads() it doesn't show the 'state_id', it's a many2one field like country_id, but I'm kinda lost here

Comment: @CZoellner I got it to work the issue was the handler was not begin updated local so any changes I did were not shown inside the json that the method recived because that json was already made, doing the commit on github so you can check my solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query on 'res.country.state' does not give any result...

Try to replace '=' by 'ilike' in your code (to make the search case insensitive and with joker (ex: %Madrid%):

```py
state_id = self.env['res.country.state'].search([('name', 'ilike', client.get('state_id', '').split('/')[0])], limit=1).id 
_logger.info("json state_id: %s", client.get('state_id', '')) 
_logger.info("state_id: %s", state_id)
```

Comment: Hey there, the problem is that the JSON that arrives whenver the json.load() is brought doesn't have the state_id I tried adding more information inside of it and doesn't show anything else, it's like the json is locked down

Comment: could you give the output og the logger.info that i suggest you ?

Comment: you can check it up at the begin of the question "Received JSON data:" I got it to fix it there was a problem with handler not begin updated whenever it's called again by the CRON, this is my new approach
https://github.com/JessieDani/PsSaleOrder/tree/main